# Custom class variables in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I am in trouble, I have created my own class and access functions of that class in my actionindex function using `myclass::myfunction()`; but I saw a surprising behavior of class variables that when I assigned a value to one variable then all other variables are also containing that value. I want to put different value in each variable but I can't

Then I used second way of accessing class i. E .

```
$obj= new myclass();
$obj->myfunction();
```

But in that case I am unable to access public variables of class in the function, they are not working

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Are you sure that the variables you are trying to use arent static?

Comment: if you want to send a variable to the view simply do `$this->variable = 'something'` now $variable is available in the view

Answer (score 0):

in action:

```
public function executeFoo($request){
  $obj= new myclass();
  $this->output = $obj->myfunction();

}
```

in fooSuccess.php

```
<?php print_r($output); ?>
```

you also could output i right from the action:

```
public function executeFoo($request){
  $obj= new myclass();
  return $this->renderText($obj->myfunction());    
}
```